# Adding text to an array and displaying the array in php

Tags: php, arrays, function, button, echo

I am trying to create a little php programme where I enter text into a text field. I then want the text to be added to an array. I do this by calling a function when the 'Add' button is clicked. After the button is clicked, I want the array entries to be displayed and the number of entries too. Here is the code I have so far, but it doesnt work :P

I have tried a few things, but nothing seemed to work.

I changed it to this now:

```
<form action="array.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Enter text here</legend>
<p>text: <input type="text" size="60" name="text"></p>
<p><input type='button' name='add' value='Add' onclick= "<?php add() ?>"></p> 
</fieldset>
</form>

<?php

global $array;

$array = array();

function add()
{

if(isset($_POST['text']))
{

array_push($array, $_POST['text']);
}

return $array;
}

$arraystring = implode(", " , $array);

echo $arraystring;

?>
```

Comment: This is not how the server-client model works. PHP executes before JavaScript.

Comment: PHP executes on the server, Javascript executes on the Client, and Javascript **CANNOT** invoke PHP code unless you use AJAX as an intermediary.

Comment: Why don't you just use some JavaScript to do that?

Comment: I don't know JavaScript. just started with php and figured this should be do-able...

Comment: PHP is executed when the page is loaded. Javascript can run anytime an event happens (such as a click). To achieve what you want in this example, in PHP, you will have to dig a lot deeper into both JS and PHP. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems here. First:

```
<script>
function add_script(){
 alert("<?PHP add(); ?>");
 }
</script>
```

The alert does not make sense here. You cannot pass data between javascript and php like that. What you would need is AJAX. The easiest solution would be [Jquery's ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). So you would need to set up a function to handle the data, a separate php script to receive it and process it and your safest bet is to return a JSON string which the initial script would process, read and return the data.

The second very big problem is the add() function - a function may not return more than one value. Whenever the interpreter sees

```
return $x;
```

The function will stop there and return whatever you've given it. The second will be ignored as the function has been terminated.

Your second option would be to post the entire form to the same script

```
<form method="post">
<!--the form inputs here-->
</form>
```

and when the "Add" button is clicked it will post the entire data to itself. and then in the PHP script you would need to add a condition to handle the case:

```
<?php
if($_POST && $_POST['text']) echo $_POST['text'];
?>
```